# serious vs. high-end

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The meaning here is that they are big, enterprise-scale switches and routers.

**Example**

> That's the reason why I have some **serious** switches and routers.

vs.

> That's the reason why I have some **high-end** switches and routers.

Is there a difference between **serious** and **high-end**? And which fit this context better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference, and which is better depends in part on who you're talking to, and in part on what you're emphasizing:

'[Serious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/serious)' does mean 'weighty and important', but it most properly means these things in an emotional or intellectual way, rather than a physical one. You're not saying that the routers are a deep philosophical matter, or that they provoke somber emotions, so it's not quite correct. I might choose to stretch the meaning in this way, especially in an informal context, but it would be a deliberate (if slight) misuse.

'[High-end](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/high-end?s=t)' places a lot of emphasis on the equipment being *expensive* and *good quality*. If that's what you're saying, it would work. However, it sounds as though you're more interesting in the high capacity and size of the equipment. Since something can be expensive and well-made while also being small and having limited capacity, it may not be exactly what you want. If that's the case, I would suggest '[heavy-duty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heavy-duty)', which conveys the sense of being made to withstand heavy usage.

Side notes: You're missing an apostrophe in "That's". Also, "the reason" and "why" are basically redundant. It's probably better to say either "That's the reason I have..." or "That's why I have..".

Comment: "High-end" does not guarantee "high-quality".  Many people think that "you get what you pay for" implies that "expensive" = "better", but there are many examples of expensive low-quality products.  A famous high-end semi-custom home-builder has a history of installing weak foundations. A prestigious auto-maker had an entire department dedicated to fixing manufacturing mistakes.  Many vintage wines have aged too long... and turned into vinegar.

Comment: @Jasper While what you say is true, the question is about word use, and when someone describes something as 'high-end', they mean that it is high-quality. Otherwise, they'd probably use 'overpriced' instead.

Answer (score 3):

*Serious* in an informal context confers indeed the meaning of "very well up to the job, actually oversized for it!"

*Big-ass* can be used in the same (very informal) way.

*High-end* on the other side, means that it is on the high-end of a technological, quality and / price scale. It may be very advanced, very good en very expensive, but not usable in a corporate environment.

So when you say you have *high-end* equipment, it doesn't mean it is big or enterprise style.

When you say you have a serious (or big-ass computer system), you may be talking about an actual mainframe in your basement. Now that is a serious computer!
On the other end, if it is an original 1960's model, I would hardly call it high-end!

The newest iPad mini is certainly a high-end gadget, but it is hardly a machine aimed at the corporate market.
If I buy a modern 4 port optical switch for use at home, that probably is a high end switch (are there budget versions for glass networks?)
However, where I work, they prefer to have rack-mounted 32-port manageable gigabit network switches with redundant power supplies and fail-over options. Those are not as high-end as my own switch, by far. But they are *bigger*, *badder* and *more serious* then my fancy toy :)

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing, but "High-end" is formally correct.  "Serious" is being used in the informal sense.  Definition #5 [from MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serious): "excessive or impressive in quality, quantity, extent, or degree [serious stereo equipment]."

I don't normally cite google dictionary as a reference, but I do like that on this word it notes that it is informal ([see definition #4](https://www.google.com/search?q=serious&oq=serious&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1351j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=define:%20serious)), whereas MW does not.